# jQuery fadein() fadeout() issue, temporarily pushes div down till it fades out completely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issues with jQuery and fading in and fading out divs. I have 3 tabs and each corresponds to a separate div that should fade in and fade out other divs out.  However When I click a tab it fades in and out, just like it should but it temporarily pushes the content down.  I could easily use CSS and `position:absolute` but that is my **ULTIMATE LAST RESORT!**  I am looking for more of a jQuery fix.

Here is a jsfiddle to display what I am trying to say: http://jsfiddle.net/swYYy/

**So far all answers given did not work as desired, they worked half the time and still had too many bugs to be effective.  I am still looking for a reasonable answer.**

Comment: well thats the work of fadeIn/fadeOut! If you need to do something more, you need to write your css/js as you want it to be shown

Comment: But its fading in and fading out at the exact same time, I think its because I have it as a callback? Is there a way to delay it...

Comment: yep, what do want exactly? How should it come?

Comment: It should look like Huangism's jsfiddle but it needs to be fully operational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take out the add() then it will work to your likings but it does not fully work

http://jsfiddle.net/swYYy/7/

I know what you are trying to do give me a sec and I will provide you with something better

Update:

Use this http://jsfiddle.net/swYYy/9/

Comment: Yes, that is the desired effect I want.  But it does not fully work, is there a way I can make it fully work?

Comment: @Skovy use `**` for bold letters. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) may help you.

Comment: try it with `[id^=page]:visible` as the selector, it seemed to work for me

Comment: Haha thanks, it worked in the main question so I assumed it would work in the comment but apparently not, I should have read the comment guidelines more closely.

Comment: close but when i click multiple tabs at the same time quickly all of them appear, I dont want that to happen or it will expand my page.  Keep in mind these divs I am fading are a couple hundred pixels tall and wide.

Comment: @Huangism If I **rapidly** click the tabs it still bugs out.  Thats the ultimate test, rapid clicking.

Comment: @Skovy I didn't add stop() because I was out of time, add the stop and it should work fine. I was hoping you would figure it out from what I gave you

Comment: @Huangism I added the stop in what I assumed is the correct spot and it still didn't work... I used absolute positioning and got it to work but still not the way I want it to.

Comment: @Skovy usually tabs always use absolute positioning since the position of the content is on top of each other. Another approach is to grab the content from some div and inject it into the same display div, so you an fadeout, change content, then fade in but that might give you issues when rapidly clicking. Give me the fiddle and the kind of behavior you ideally want and it is most likely doable

Comment: @Huangism Don't work about it, I appreciate the help and concern but the way I have it now it will be fully operational and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Tested with just the tab2 click:

```
$('#tab2').click(function() { 
   $('#page1, #page3').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(function() {
      $('#page2').fadeIn(1000);
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated & short fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/swYYy/12/

Here goes the JS code:

```
$('#page2').hide();
$('#page3').hide();
$('.settings-options-tab').click(function() { 
    var index=$('.settings-options-tab').index(this);
    $('div[id^=page]:visible').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('.settings-pages').hide();
        $('.settings-pages:eq('+index+')').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
​
```

Comment: If I **rapidly** click the tabs it still bugs out too.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I changed the time from 1000 ms to 300 ms and now I can't get it to bug out again so I think this will work.  Thanks.

Comment: did it work? I thought it did, since you had accepted the answer :/

Comment: It did but I believe if you double click a tab it no longer works, thats what was happening for me... I kept getting an issue.  I resorted to positioning absolute and I got it to work fine but no the way I would like it to be.